# Lisp program that duplicates an element of a list using a list of integers

Tags: list, syntax, duplicates, lisp, common-lisp

I'm working on a program that takes a list of elements and each individual element is duplicated based on an integer contained in a 2nd list of integers. for example if I had a list of

```
(A B C D)
```

being duplicated by:

```
(1 5 4 2)
```

I would have

```
(A B B B B B C C C C D D)
```

So far I have

```
(defun COPY (X Y) 
  (if (zerop Y) 
      nil 
      (cons S (COPY X (1 - Y)))))
```

Of course this is only duplicating a single element a single number of times. Does anybody have a good idea how to go about this?

Comment: `1` is not a function, so `(1 ...)` is an error. You want to call function `-` on arguments `1` and `Y`, like so: `(- 1 Y)`

Comment: `1-` is a function

Comment: @RainerJoswig I see a space in OP's question, it might be a typo but the code as written has a problem.

Comment: @coredump: no doubt, there is a space - but maybe it was a typo or similar. Sometimes newcomers might not understand that and write an extra  space.

Comment: there's a typo there, it's `(cons X` and then `(COPY X (1- Y) ...`. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`mapcan`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) and
[`make-list`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mk_lis.htm) (which is the library version of your `copy`):

```
(mapcan (lambda (letter num)
          (make-list num :initial-element letter))
        '(A B C D) '(1 5 4 2))
==> (A B B B B B C C C C D D)
```

or just

```
(mapcan #'copy '(A B C D) '(1 5 4 2))
```

If you are required to use simple recursion, you can also write

```
(defun copy-list-elements (elements counts)
  (and elements counts
       (let ((count (pop counts)))
         (if (plusp count)
             (cons (car elements)
                   (copy-list-elements elements
                                       (cons (1- count) counts)))
             (copy-list-elements (cdr elements)
                                 counts)))))
(copy-list-elements '(A B C D E) '(1 5 4 0 2))
==> (A B B B B B C C C C E E)
```

Note that the recursive version is longer and probably slower.

Answer (score 3):

Loop over the two lists, call `copy`, and append the results.

```
(loop for letter in letters
      for count in counts
      nconcing (copy letter count))
```